# Ckeditor, create php file to store in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I'm using CKeditor but I'm not working out how to create the php file that stores editing textareas in MySql DB.
I'm quite newbie in php/mysql..
javascript code of CKeditor calls is:

```
$(’#my_div’).ckeip({
e_url: ’test.php’,
data: {
example_var : ’example_value’,
example_var2 : ’example_value2’
}
)};
```

What I have to write in test.php to making it store data of ckeditor in MySql?
Should I create a new table in database first ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is create a new MYSQL table with two columns. One as an id for the textarea and then the other column to store the text. For a basic tutorial about MYSQL and PHP check out W3School http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: Thank you. I think I can create this table you say but then? My struggle is the php file call by e_url: ’test.php’. What I have to write in it to make it communicate with new table ?

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to CKEditor, too. But it seems like it would be quite easy once you get the data from the editor into a javascript variable, like:

```
var editorData = $('my_div').ckeditorGet().getData();
```

You can then put editorData into a hidden input field and then submit it to the PHP file that you're going to create. On that PHP file you would take it with something like:

```
$theData = $_GET["name_of_the_hidden_input_field"];
//here comes the PHP code for inserting $theData into mysql
```